# Ads provider for Windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, ads

Does anybody know ad providers for Windows 8 apps apart from MS and AdDuplex? I'd love to find another one since AdDuplex is simply not working. I'm currently implementing ih-house apps functionality but would rather use a ready one like AdMob's one for example.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 8 you only have support for

- PubCenter
- AdDuplex
- Inmobi

All the rest are "currently" only available for Windows Phone

However in AdRotator we were able to get most of that list to work through their WebAPI's and we plan to expand WebAPI support to all platforms in AdRotator V2 (http://getadrotator.codeplex.com)

Comment: Oh and with AdRotator you can also enable your OWN ad :D

Comment: Here's the link for InMobi's Windows 8 SDK. http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=InMobi_Ad_SDK_for_Windows_8_Store_Applications

Answer (score 2):

Leadbolt can also be used:
http://www.leadbolt.com/blog/2013/06/official-launch-of-leadbolt-windows-8-sdk

If you have used some of them, please share the results you're getting (fill rate, eCPM).

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. LeadBolt has pop-up alerts based sdk for XAML, Audio ads as well as HTML5 ads for Webview elements. so basically you can have Text/Banner html ads placed in WebView in your app. Some work has to be done to make the edges and the webview content look better. I have verified that all of these work but in my app i had to use HTML ads. I could see 1$+ eCPM one day and a bit lower some days! In any case, fill rates are much better!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know only Microsoft pub center and adduplex were available. now also inmobi provides SDK for advertisements for w8 (js+xaml)

Answer (score 0):

See a list below. More info here.

[AdRotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/)
Microsoft PubCenter
AdDuplex
Google AdMob
Inner-Active  / Nokia Ad Exchange 
MobFox
Smaato (Not for Non Location aware projects, see above link) 
Default House Ads - A project based Ad the developer implements (docs pending) 
Support for no ad display 
Both Location Aware and Non Location Aware libs now available

Comment: Hi Zhiming,

I have used the Ad Rotator in a WP7. As far as I know only the MS and AdDuplex have Windows 8 SDKs. For example AdMob which is on this list currently doesn't have such an SDK. So this list applies to WP8 and not Windows8.

Comment: MediaBrix, Inmobi, Adduplex, MS Ads, ADTECH etc have ads for Windows 8. checkout the list at http://services.windowsstore.com

Answer (score 0):

I've been using leadbolt in the last week with this results:

Views/Imps  Clicks  ECPM    EPC CTR Revenue

12,600          128 $0.00   $0.00   1.02%   $0.00

Let's sum up: 12600 impressions with 0 revenue.

I'll try inmobi very soon and I'll let you know!!!

Comment: hmm.. are you using HTML banner ads? if so looks like they give only for clicks not for impressions! Did you try the Text + Banner ads?

Comment: Go check out MediaBrix and ADTECH and let us know

Answer (score 0):

MediaBrix, Inmobi, MS ads, LeadBolt etc. have ads. Checkout the list at http://services.windowsstore.com and filter by Advertising.

Also note that ADTECH has recently mentioned in their site that they have a new Windows 8 SDK.  http://www.adtech.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Leadbolt and PubCenter for a while, with very poor results in revenue. A few weeks ago I discovered DesktopAd (www.desktopad.com) which gives me 10x the revenue than I was receiving with PubCenter, and also a fill rate almost 100%. For Windows 8 developers it's worth to give it a try.